# Qt6 Connect Signal to Lambda Function

Tags: c++, c++17, qt6

I'm using a `DataRouter` class to handle communication with a `QSerialPort` (and then communicate the results elsewhere). The connected device sends a status package every second or so, and I would like to read it without polling the device. I tried directly using `QSerialPort`'s `waitForReadyRead` function, but no matter how long I set the wait time, it always timed out. Looking [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html) I saw signals can be connected to Lambda functions. Now I'm trying to connect `QSerialPort`'s `readyRead` signal to a Lambda which calls my `on_dataRecieved` function but I get the error `C2665:"QObject::connect: none of the 3 overloads could convert all of the argument types`. Below is an example of what I have:

DataRouter.h

```
template<class SerialPort>
class DataRouter
{
public:
    DataRouter ();
private slots:
    on_dataRecieved();
private:
    shared_ptr<SerialPort> m_port;
};
```

DataRouter.cpp

```
template<class SerialPort>
DataRouter<SerialPort>::DataRouter()
{
    m_port = std::make_shared<SerialPort>()
    QObject::connect(m_port, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, [=](){this->on_dataRecieved();})
}

template<class SerialPort>
void DataRouter<SerialPort>::on_dataRecieved()
{
 //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "target" is not QObject you need to use the following overload of [connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4). The problem is that, you are trying to use non-QObject as "context" to determine the lifetime of the connection and that's not possible. To mitigate it you will need to release the connection somehow on DataRouter's destruction; one way is to store what `connect()` will have returned and call `disconnect` on it later on.

As for the signal coming from a smart pointer, have you tried this:
`connect(m_port->get(), &QSerialPort::readyRead, &DataRouter::on_dataRecieved);`

Comment: I just tried what you suggested, unfortunately it gives me the same error as before "C2665 ... None of the 4 overloads..."

Comment: what if you try wrapping `on_dataRecieved` into a lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Your `m_port` is not entity of `QSerialPort` class, that's why you don't have  `QSerialPort::readyRead` that can be emitted from it. `template<class SerialPort>` doesn't do what you what, it is just name of templated parameter.
You probably wanted something like this:

DataRouter.h

```
class DataRouter : QObject
{
public:
    DataRouter ();
private slots:
    on_dataRecieved();
private:
    QSerialPort* m_port;
};
```

DataRouter.cpp

```
DataRouter::DataRouter()
{
    m_port = new QSerialPort(this);
    connect(m_port, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &DataRouter::on_dataRecieved);
    // or connect(m_port, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, [this](){this->on_dataRecieved();});
}

void DataRouter::on_dataRecieved()
{
 //Do stuff
}
```

You don't have to wrap Qt classes in smart pointers as long, as you provide parent class for them. Memory freed when parent is destructed.

Comment: You were right about needing to change ```m_port``` from the template type to ```QSerialPort```. The ```DataRouter``` class does not inherent from ```QObject``` so it can't be the parent in the constructor for ```new QSerialPort (this)```. Does the ```on_dataRecieved``` method need to belong to a class which inherits from ```QObject``` in order to be a slot?

Comment: You are right, about the fact DataRouter can't be parent, my bad. As for your question, I don't think it needs to be, however, I might be mistaken. You can write connect part using lambda, like you did in your example: connect(m_port, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, [this](){this->on_dataRecieved();}); This didn't require DataRouter to be QObject.

Comment: I've tried using the lambda in the connect like you suggested but it's giving me the same error as before. Though now the suggestions are saying "no known conversion from ```DataRouter* ```to``` const QObject*``` for 3rd argument".

Comment: I have updated my answer, now DataRouter inherits from QObject and you can use it as parent and use connect.